# validate url and domain field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that contain input fields one for domain and one for folder name. now i want to validate these two fields before submitting the form.I am using [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

how can i validate my fields on custom build rules

1) domain url will not contain http:// or / at the end

```
   http://google.com wrong
   google.com/     wrong
   google.com      correct
```

2) folder name without any "/" at the start or at the end

```
   foldername/ wrong
   /foldername wrong
   foldername  correct
```

this is the code that i am trying.

```
<form id="f">
    <label for="domain">Domain</label>
    <input type="text" value="subdomainname.abc.com" id="domain" name="domain" maxlength="50" size="30">

    <label for="newfolder">Folder Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="newfolder" maxlength="50" size="30" id="newfolder">

    <input type="submit" value"configure">
</form>
```

this is validation

```
$(function() {
    var v = $('#f').validate({
        rules: {
            domain: {
                required: true
                 // custome rule 
            },
            newfolder: {
                required: true,
                // custome rule
            }
        },
        messages: {
            domain: {
                required: "Enter a valid url"
            },
            newfolder:{
                required: "Folder name incorrect"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submit');

         }
    });          
});
```

Comment: You simply need to write custom methods following the documentation for the `addMethod` method and the appropriate regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a regular expression, here are the regular expressions you need:

[URL Validation](http://regexr.com/39vqj)  This mateches {anything}.{anything} if you need it to be {anything}.{only certain addresses} use this regexp [Regexr](http://regexr.com/39vqm)

---

For the folder validation you are effectively just looking for a word use this one [Regexr](http://regexr.com/39vqp), even if it doesn't help you check out http://www.regexr.com it's a cool site and will help you with regular expressions. I have found it useful many times